# Symfony form event display dumps and get data-attributes

Tags: php, symfony

I using `FormEvents` in Symfony FormType.

I have add a `data-attribute` to one of my field and I'm trying to get this attribute in my `PRE_SUBMIT` form event.

I want to make a condition inside this form event to add another field if the `data-attribute` is `true`.

The problem is, I don't know how to get the `data-attribute` value in this form event.
Every `dump()` I write are not displayed or I don't find where in the Symfony profiler.

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) use ($refreshIpV4s, $refreshIpV6s) {
    $form = $event->getForm();
    $data = $event->getData();

    dump($form->get('server')->has('data-mysql'));
    dump($form->get('server')->getData());
    dump($form['server']['data-mysql']);    

    if ($form['server']['data-mysql']) {
        $form->add('database', CheckboxType::class, [
            'label' => 'domain.form.associated_databases',
            'translation_domain' => 'front',
            'required' => false,
        ]);
    }
});
```

This dumps are tests, I don't know if they are good or not, I'm just testing what I get with this.

How can I see this `dump()` when the form event is used ?
How can I get my `data-attribute` value ?

Know where dumps are displayed will be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: put `exit;` after your last `dump` and submit your form you will see these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Symfony 2.6 you see the dump() result within the profiler. For receiving dumps during a redirect, use `intercept_redirects` and set it to `true`. You can find it under `app/config/config_dev.yml` under the `web_profiler` option.

Submit the form again and wait until the redirect is intercepted and you should see your dump results.